# Android CSV import issue

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file into my SQLite database. I am currently useing a button to run the method as I am not sure where to call it so it will load the data when the app is launched. When I call it in the on create of my launch screen there is an issue.

This is the error.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/Users/b00619342/Downloads/VegT(DBCodedNeedPreSetD)/app/src/main/assets/brekfasttable.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Heres the code

```
public void brekCSV() throws IOException {

    String[] row = null;
    //need to change when the project is moved to a new location
    String csvBrek = "C:/Users/b00619342/Downloads/VegT(DBCodedNeedPreSetD)/app/src/main/assets/brekfasttable.csv";

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvBrek));

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] tokens = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_BREK +
                "VALUES(" + tokens[0] + "," + tokens[1] + "," + tokens[2] + "," + tokens[3] + "," + tokens[4] + "," + tokens[5] + "," + tokens[6] + ")");
    }

    db.close();

}//end of brekCSV
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Android device is not your Windows desktop.  There is no "C:".  You need to put the file on your device and use the correct path to where it is on your device where the code runs.

Comment: Sorry I am currently using Android Studio's emulator!

Comment: The emulated device is still not your Windows desktop PC.  The emulator mimics the entire hardware of a real device and runs the Android operating system.  It has no awareness of the Windows system hosting the emulator.  It is meant to be just like a real device without the need to pay for the hardware.

Comment: You can use [`adb push`](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to copy the file from your Windows system to the (emulated) device's sdcard.

Comment: Ahh I understand now. So how would I do that code wise?

Comment: Your Android app can't get files from a different device (eg your Windows desktop).  You need to use adb to put the file on the device.  Or put the file on a web server and download it using the device (that you could do from your app, if you knew where it would be hosted).

Comment: On my device (an old one, with Android 4.2) if I uploaded a file named 'brekfasttable.csv' to the sdcard, the path to open it would be `"/mnt/sdcard/brekfasttable.csv"`.  Some devices use a different path, also depending on whether they have an "internal sdcard" or a (real) "external" sdcard.

Comment: I am starting to get a better understanding of this but im just not sure how to code it.

Comment: For the code, just change the string you have.  Change "C:/Users/b00619342/Downloads/VegT(DBCodedNeedPreSetD)/app/src/main/assets/brekfasttable.csv" to "/mnt/sdcard/brekfasttable.csv".

Comment: Like this?  String csvBrek = "/mnt/sdcard/brekfasttable.csv";  Still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes.  Now you need to put the file on the device.  This is not a matter of coding, just a matter of procedure you need to do put the file there.

Comment: the file is currently in the assets folder. What would be the next step?

Comment: Open a terminal, cd to the assets directory, and run `adb push brekfasttable.csv /mnt/sdcard/`

Comment: A question: is this a file that will be shipped as part of the app and never change without making a new version of the app, or is it data that a user should obtain, somehow, and import when they want?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for read file in buffer reader.

```
String filename="brekfasttable.csv";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(filename)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

or

```
String filename="brekfasttable.csv";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mainMenu.this.getAssets().open(filename)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Trying this now, getting "Cannot resolve  symbol context"

Comment: Ok, no problem replace your context with your Activity name .this like ActivityA.this

Comment: My activity is called mainMenu and this is what I did but getAssests is now giving me an error.  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mainMenu.getAssets().open(filename)));

Comment: Really you have mainMenu activity because your activity name should start with small case its not good and above my comment i have written after activity name put dot this,  like  mainMenu.this

Comment: so would it now be mainMenu.this.open(filename))); ??

Comment: Now i have replaced my code check now. may be work for you.

Comment: Just replaced it and now getApplicationContext() is getting the same cannot resolve error.

Comment: Tried the second one and it says its not an enclosing class. Thoughts?